# CSS: Left-align and right-align text on the same line

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, text-alignment

Stack Overflow has questions asking how to both left-align and right-align text on 1 line. I couldn't find an answer that works for multi-line text.

---

How do I right-align an inline element on its own line within a paragraph of text that wraps around multiple lines? When the inline element is in the middle of a line, it should skip past the text in its way and be at the end of the current line.

**Example Code:**

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    <span class="lil-green"></span>
    elit. Pellentesque in vestibulum purus, et pharetra tellus. Etiam et ague tortor.
    <span class="lil-red"></span>
</p>
```

> [image: 310H55V]
>
> Simple Mockup

The solution should work even when the text container element is resized.

Comment: Do you need it to be on the final line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the `float` property is for. Use `float: right` inside the rule of that element. You can learn more about the `float` property at [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> `right`
>
> The element must float on the right side of its containing block.

Float makes text wrap around an image or other element.